# Options to show images when on the console

Tags: linux, console, images

When I am on the console (the tty, the virtual terminal, which you reach with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-6</kbd>, not a terminal emulator), what options do I have to view images, tiff, whatever that's not text?

Comment: You mean the virtual terminal as opposed to a terminal emulator? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Comment: @Graeme: yes, that's it.

Comment: see also: Gate One

Answer (score 11):

You can use the library from [AA-Project](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

Applications:

- xine-console [video]
- xaos [fractals/mandelbrod]
- vlc [video]
- aview [photos]
- ... a.m.o

Answer (score 9):

First off you must make sure the framebuffer is enabled, there is absolutely no way to view images in text mode. Once you have the framebuffer enabled, you can use the program `fbi` to view images.

> Package: fbi
>
> Linux frame buffer image viewer
>
> This is an image viewer for Linux frame buffer devices.  It has
> built-in support for a number of common image file formats.  For
> unknown files, it tries to use convert from the ImageMagick package
> as an external converter.
> It also includes fbgs, a Postscript and PDF viewer.

Answer (score 9):

### Updated answer

**Install [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger)**, a filemanager for the console. It shows colored images if the requiered programs are installed. Look into their [`rc.conf`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rc.conf) and search for `preview.*image` to learn how they do it and which programs they use and what requirements they have. Here is a list of programs they try to use (but better look into the `rc.conf` file:

- w3m
- iterm2
- terminology
- urxvt
- urxvt-full
- kitty
- ueberzug

### Old answer

Many images are coloured, hence you may use [libcaca’s](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) ASCII image viewer (`cacaview`) and image to text converter (`img2iso`).

- To browse images, use the *ASCII image browser*:

  ```
    cacaview /usr/share/pixmaps/*.*
  ```
- Convert images to text-based coloured files:

  ```
    img2txt -W 150 penguins_mating.png > penguins_mating.txt
  ```
- View movies and videos in text console:

  ```
    mplayer -vo caca https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Big_Buck_Bunny_medium.ogv
  ```

  Mostly you don’t need the option `-vo caca` if you view your video in a text-only environment (terminal with ssh-connection, virtual terminal etc.). By default you’ll get the noncolored text-output (i.e. `-vo aa`), but color may be better.

For Fedora and Ubuntu the package `caca-utils` has to be installed.

[Read here](https://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Aalib,_caca) for more information.

[image]

Comment: `cacaview` in Ubuntu 21.10 opens a new window, it does *not* print the image out (in ASCII with colours) in the terminal.

Comment: @Flimm Use ranger as described above. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [a framebuffer device](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/). The framebuffer mechanism is the one used to display Tux when you boot.

There is also the [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) used to display ASCII-art images.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? How would one go about using these tools?

Comment: It depends very much on your hardware and your needs. You should provide more details in your question and give context.

Comment: Not my question. I am pointing out that when answering a question, you should include the details on how to do it. You are just giving two links to external sources, something we try to avoid. The idea is that answers on the SE sites are self-contained.

Comment: Of course, but there is not just one way to use these tools. And there is not much context in the question so...

Answer (score 2):

`mplayer` has a framebuffer driver (2 versions, in case one doesn't work). Use

```
mplayer -vo fbdev [or fbdev2] <filename>
```

For images, `fbi` and `fim` work. Whatever else these two can't handle, you can probably convert to images on the fly ( `imagemagick` works like magic), so you have everything covered.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can show any image format fullscreen :

```
ffmpeg -i image.ext -s $(< /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size tr , x) \
       -vcodec rawvideo -f image2 -pix_fmt bgra -y /dev/fb0 &>/dev/null && read
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library today today named [SVGAlib](https://www.svgalib.org/). It directly handles the video card, with user-space drivers (imported mainly from X).

It has no drivers to most current video cards, but

- it has VESA output driver (i.e. essentially it can handle the output with the BIOS drivers)
- it has fbdev drivers (it handles `/dev/fb0` as a video card, thus essentially it uses the kernel drivers).

There are many softwares using SVGALib, for example mplayer (for video output), and answering your question, the [xzgv image viewer](https://xzgv-image-viewer.soft112.com/).

Although you will have to compile them from source, because Linux distribution developers all think since roughly a decade, that X (with continuous nice, never-fulfilled promises like kgi, ggi, and today wayland) are the future.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is limited to native linux consoles that are frame-buffer enabled. This option will give you full resolution real images and real video (not ascii-art) without `X11` or `wayland` or `mir`.

As of 2018, debian offers a package `fim` which includes an image viewer `fim` and a document viewer `fimgs`. For `fimgs`, the default resolution is 96x96, which you'll probably find inadequate. I find that calling it with option `-r 256x256` is sufficient. These two programs are meant to be 'modernized' versions of other programs also available in debian, `fbi` and `fbgs`. A particular disappointment with the older program `fbgs` is that it renders slowly and will render an entire pdf file before displaying even a single page, so if you have a many-paged document, you'll be waiting a long long time.

There are several programs not specific to framebuffer operation that have fine framebuffer support. The `w3m` web browser will display images when support package `w3m-img` is installed. The `feh` image viewer works in a frame buffer console, as does `vlc` for video.

All this is all very well and good, but in order to use any of these options you will first need to set things up.

The good news is that pretty much all modern linux distributions ship kernels with the framebuffer available. What isn't commonly done is configuring that frame buffer to be actually used. For that, if you are using the `grub` bootloader, you will need to make sure the following exists in your file `/etc/default/grub` (your specific resolution number may be different):

```
  GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
```

And you will need to make sure the following line is commented out:

```
  #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

After that, you will need to update grub by running `update-grub` and will need to reboot for the changes to take effect.

You also may need to add your user to the `video` permissions group:

```
  usermod -a -G video <user_name>
```

Some programs may require special capability access. According to my notes, that is the case with `fbi`, but I see on my system it is not the case for `fim`. Go figure. In any event the command for that is:

```
  setcap 'cap_sys_tty_config+ep' /usr/bin/fbi
```

A program that I can not recommend, and have only had trouble with, is `fbterm`. It kept messing with my color schemes for `emacs`, `mc`, `less` and other programs, and I recall that it wouldn't play nicely will `tmux`.

An important note about using `vlc` in a framebuffer console: I found that sometimes, in a way I wasn't able to reliably reproduce, `vlc` would freeze and not release the framebuffer, short of "alt-sysrq"-ing the machine to reboot. Sometimes, this happened when attempting to switch to another virtual consoles; sometimes when experimenting with what `vlc` keystroke commands would work. You have been warned.

Comment: there's also the term emulator [terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) that can be run on a framebuffer console (`terminology --nowm`).  the included utility `tycat` can embed images.

Comment: Is that the one from the people of the 'enlightenment' desktop? I evaluated it maybe a year ago and it was buggy then, but if you can vouch for it, great!

Comment: i just started looking at it and can't confirm lack of bugs, sorry.  it's working mostly-ok on one system (intel gpu), doesn't work on another (nvidia proprietary driver, untested but likely works under nouveau).  set `XKB_DEFAULT_{LAYOUT,VARIANT,OPTIONS}` env variables for xkb layouts (though AltGr doesn't seem to work right atm).

Answer (score -7):

None. You need some kind of display server to display images. Xserver, mir, wayland or similar provide the interfaces for images. getty is designed to emulate text terminals and doesn't have the ability to display images.

Comment: I kind of disagree. How would the Tux be displayed at boottime ? http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KNOPPIX_booting.png  ;-)

Comment: Framebuffer. Without enabling frame-buffering it can't be done, should've mentioned that. But, They also mentioned being on a *real* terminal. Forgetting that they're not on a real terminal, on a real terminals (vt1000) or similar I'm fairly certain it's not possible.

Comment: Many real terminals have the ability to draw graphics.  Graphics capability was a selling point in the 1980s.  And `getty` isn't emulating anything.