# How does Raspbian draw images on the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, images

When you turn a Raspberry Pi on, it displays three (or four) pictures of raspberries in the top-left corner of the screen. Now, as far as I know, you cannot draw images or any other non-text content on the text mode terminal. How does Raspbian manage it? Even weirder, this happens before I start X..

The answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146486/how-to-draw-a-single-pixel-in-a-terminal?rq=1) question, for example, says that it is impossible to draw images on the terminal without talking to X directly

Comment: You can read all about how to program the raspberry pi framebuffer in this [interesting series of articles](http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.fr/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html).

Answer (score 1):

The raspberries are not drawn on a text only screen, nor is X used.

This is part of the [bootsplash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootsplash) image and displayed in VESA/VGA **graphics** mode, which also displays your boot text in a higher resolution (i.e. smaller characters) than the non-graphical 80x25 screen.