# How to display images in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, images

How do I display images in the terminal? I am on Mac OSX mountain lion (10.8.5), and the answers in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123674/can-i-see-images-and-watch-movies-inside-the-terminal-emulator) don't work on OSX. Is it possible at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233105/how-can-i-display-an-image-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pxl](https://github.com/ichinaski/pxl) is the best tool I have found for xterm-256color terminals.

iTerm has specific tools to inline images (search `iTerm imgcat` and `imgls`) but those are kind of cheats (that work great :D).

[gif-cli](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/gif-cli) works for GIFs, but ... not well at all. Its author has tools for videos and images, too.

pxl:

[image]

imgcat: Just shows the image, with no scaling or anything. The screenshot was bigger than SO's limit, unfortunately. (SO should include a compression mechanism. ) Supports a variety of formats, including animated GIFs.

Update: [Kitty](http://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) is a cross-platform terminal emulator that supports custom protocols that allow it to render bitmaps. It's very feature-rich, I suggest you try it.

---

Comment: pxl is my new favorite, really nice `go get` away install too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- `xdg-open` to open a viewer from terminal
- convert to ascii art `asciiview`
- use `vlc` to output video as ascii art

Comment: Have you installed them. I know 100% that you can get `vlc` for mac.

Comment: @John, if you want to just use existing Mac tools without installing anything, why not just use the terminal command `open` on the image files to open them in Preview?

Comment: I use `apt-get` and these URLs: `http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/`. If you are using Mac, or Microsoft, then you have to do it the hard way (does mac have a package manager?)